# avoiding code duplication when assigning events

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is a good way to assign the same event triggered behavior to multiple of elements are a time

currently I just duplicate the code like this, but this is obviously not optimal

```
  $('.recipient #shipment_recipient_attributes_country_code').changeOrDelayedKey(function(e) {
    cargoflux.resetCarrierProductPriceFields();
    cargoflux.getAvailableCarrierProducts();
  }, 1000, 'keyup');

  $('#shipment_recipient_attributes_zip_code').changeOrDelayedKey(function(e) {
    cargoflux.resetCarrierProductPriceFields();
    cargoflux.getAvailableCarrierProducts();
    console.log('recp zip code')
  }, 2000, 'keyup');

  $('.sender #shipment_sender_attributes_country_code').changeOrDelayedKey(function(e) {
    cargoflux.resetCarrierProductPriceFields();
    cargoflux.getAvailableCarrierProducts();
  }, 1000, 'keyup');

  $('#shipment_sender_attributes_zip_code').changeOrDelayedKey(function(e) {
    cargoflux.resetCarrierProductPriceFields();
    cargoflux.getAvailableCarrierProducts();
  }, 2000, 'keyup');
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: 1) Multi-select, 2) stop redefining the same function over and over and just use a reference to a single function.

Comment: Put the duplicated code in a function, call that?

Comment: Uh yeah, that's the point of a class : `$('.someClass').changeOrDelayedKey(...`

Comment: you can split the queries with a coma `,` like `$('#firstquery, #secondquery')`, and you can also define a function that you will reuse as callback for each changeOrDelayedKey

Comment: Note: As you have id searches, and IDs must be unique on the page, the preceding `.recipient` has no effect on the search query (other than to slow down the search) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class for all the elements, and add a `data-delay` attribute for the delay, and then apply the events to each element:

The markup:

```
<input class="someClass" id="some_id" data-delay="2000" ... />
```

The jQuery:

```
$(".someClass").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.changeOrDelayedKey(function(e) {
      cargoflux.resetCarrierProductPriceFields();
      cargoflux.getAvailableCarrierProducts();
    }, $this.data('delay'), 'keyup');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the HTML add a common class to each element in question, and as you have different data requirements (the timing varies) you can iterate over them and use `data-` attributes to hold to delay:

```
  $('.someclass').each(function(){
     $(this).changeOrDelayedKey(function(e) {
        cargoflux.resetCarrierProductPriceFields();
        cargoflux.getAvailableCarrierProducts();
  }, $(this).data('delay'), 'keyup');
```

And the elements will have `data-delay="1000"` or `data-delay="2000"` added (as well as the class you chose).

An alternative, if you have groups of fixed timings, is to apply different classes to the different time requirements and share a function:

e.g.

```
  function reset() {
        cargoflux.resetCarrierProductPriceFields();
        cargoflux.getAvailableCarrierProducts();
  }

  $('.someclass1000').changeOrDelayedKey(reset, 1000, 'keyup');
  $('.someclass2000').changeOrDelayedKey(reset, 2000, 'keyup');
```

You then just add `class="someclass1000"` or `class="someclass2000"` to get the desired effect.

Note: As you have id searches, and IDs must be unique on the page, the preceding `.recipient` has no effect on the search query (other than to slow down the search).